# C# Get Directories runs slow

Tags: c#, performance, text-files

```
foreach (string directory in Directory.GetDirectories(SearchDirectory, "*",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
{
//This is slow i have many files/directories here.
}
```

i Search through many directories checking textfiles for small amounts of information and the code works fine i just would like to be able to loop through all the directories with a progress bar of some sort that is not lagging the program does not seem to keep up with Directory.GetDirectories. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `Directory.EnumerateDirectories` to process one after the other instead of pre-loading all.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That wouldn't help with having a progress bar though.

Comment: @Adam Is your problem that calling `GetDirectories` is slow or that your processing of each one takes time and that's why you want a progress bar?

Comment: progressbar.Invoke a change in value on a progress bar. Calculate a percent based on the number of directories. WinForms or WPF should probably be specified.

Comment: I would like it to be faster, if possible, but I want it to run smoothly either way right now when it searches my program almost freezes until the search is complete

Comment: Therefore I cannot have a progress bar when my form is froze.

Comment: You would need something like a [BackgroundWorker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.7.2) to thread the UI interface. There are numerous ways to thread a UI, the `BackgroundWorker` is just one of the easiest to implement in my opinion. [Here's a tutorial on how to use it](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-progressbar-control/)

Comment: If you are checking textfiles maybe you should be using [GetFiles()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_). You can get al the *.txt or whatever extension you want in a folder and its subfolders and then treat them acordingly.

Comment: Yes, but *what* do you want to be faster? Is it your processing that is slow of the call to `GetDirectories`? To prevent your program from freezing is another issue entirely. You have multiple questions here, you should be providing a [mcve], but first go and read up on WinForms/WPF development, there's a million articles out there telling you how to not lock your UI thread.

Comment: Getdirectories is the slow part..

Comment: How long does it take to call `GetDirectories`?

Comment: 10-15 seconds for it to complete, as I stated my form is froze until completion too.

Comment: And if you take out the body of the `for` loop, is it quicker?

Comment: Not by much. Maybe a couple seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directory.EnumerateDirectories Helped me enough with what i was trying to accomplish it allowed for a progress bar instead of GetDirectories.